# Define global function within \begingroup ... \endgroup

Tags: grouping, definition, l3keys

I have a command that accepts optional arguments as key-value pairs, handled by the `l3keys` package. I use `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` to `\keys_set:nn` the keys in order to process set options only for the current command invocation.

However, this command shall make some global Document command available to the end user, using `\NewDocumentCommand`. Due to grouping, this will only be local.
However, a `\global` before the definition results in the error

```
! You can't use a prefix with `\begingroup'.
<to be read again> 
                   \group_begin: 
l.93 ... = H, description = ab fg.]{Abfg}{Ab_{fg}}
                                                  
? h
I'll pretend you didn't say \long or \outer or \global or \protected.

?
```

so it seems that this is not intended.

---

The following is a minimal (non-) working example, not using the grouping and thus overwriting the set keys.
The intended grouping and global definition is marked in the comments, adding these lines produces the error above.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { categories }
  {
    key       .tl_set:N   = \l__category_key_tl,
    key       .default:n  = \c_novalue_tl
    % More keys ommited
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn\tl_if_novalue:nF{ V F }

\NewDocumentCommand{\DeclareCategory}{ O{} m}
  {
  %  \begingroup
      \keys_set:nn{ categories }{#1}
 %     \exp_args:NNc\global\NewDocumentCommand{#2}{ }
      \exp_args:Nc\NewDocumentCommand{#2}{ }
        {
          %Do some stuff here with #2:
          called:~#2,~
          % Do some other stuff, using the \l__category_key_tl token list
          Value~is:~\tl_use:N\l__category_key_tl
        }
%    \endgroup
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
  \DeclareCategory[ key = foo]{A}
  \DeclareCategory[ key = foo2]{B}
  
  \A

  \B
\end{document}
```

**How can I make such a global definition within the group?**

Comment: please always provide a test file not just fragments. `\global` has to be immediately before a primitive assignment, you can't use it before any higher level constructs eg `\global\newcommand` doesn't do anything useful. It is hard to guess what you are doing (and `\setkeys` is from keyval not l3keys

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you are right, I updated the question to clarify

Comment: since you are defining commands with no arguments not really any point in newdocumentcommand (especially as it would geerate an error on the second use when the command was not new) gust use `\gdef` (or perhaps better here a global expl3 level definition.)

Comment: I thought one should prefer to use `\NewDocumentCommand` for user-level commands. Also, actually there are arguments, but I ommitted them for brevity, and the \DeclareCategory command is to be used only once, so the error thrown on second use will be intended.
I could parse the arguments without \NewDocumentCommand of course, what would be the expl3 way to do a `\gdef` in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. `\NewDocumentCommand` is not a global declaration;
2. you want to use the values you set to the keys in the replacement text, not the token list names.

The first problem could be solved by first setting the keys to a “standard state” so avoiding the need for a group.

The second problem is solved by “controlling the expansion” using an expanded definition. Here I use the group strategy and `\cs_new_protected:cpx` which acts globally.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { categories }
  {
    key       .tl_set:N   = \l__category_key_tl,
    key       .default:n  = \c_novalue_tl
    % More keys omitted
  }

\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \tl_if_novalue:n { V } { p, T, F, TF }

\NewDocumentCommand{\DeclareCategory}{ O{} m}
  {
    \keissler_category_define:nn { #1 } { #2 }
  }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \keissler_category_define:nn
  {
     \group_begin:
     \keys_set:nn { categories }{#1}
     \cs_new_protected:cpx { #2 }
       {
         \exp_not:n
           {
             %Do some stuff here with #2:
             called:~#2,~Value~is:~
           }
         \exp_not:V \l__category_key_tl
       }
     \group_end:
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\DeclareCategory[key = foo]{A}
\DeclareCategory[key = foo2]{B}
  
\A

\B

\end{document}
```

[image]

A different approach, which can be used when you have a small number of keys.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { categories }
 {
  key       .tl_set:N   = \l__category_key_tl,
  key       .default:n  = \c_novalue_tl
  % More keys omitted
 }

\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \tl_if_novalue:n { V } { p, T, F, TF }

\NewDocumentCommand{\DeclareCategory}{ O{} m }
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { categories } { #1 }
  \keissler_category_define:nnV { #1 } { #2 } \l__category_key_tl
  \group_end:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \keissler_category_define:nnn
 {
  \cs_new_protected:cpn { #2 }
   {
    %Do some stuff here with #2:
    called:~#2,~Value~is:~#3
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \keissler_category_define:nnn { nnV }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\DeclareCategory[ key = foo]{A}
\DeclareCategory[ key = foo2]{B}
  
\A

\B

\end{document}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of the indirection with `\keissler_category_define:nn`? Is'nt this redundant?

Comment: @MaximilianKeßler It's the recommended way, actually. Use it whenever the body of the definition is more than three or four lines.

Comment: why is this? can you point me to some source explaining the advantages of this?

Comment: @MaximilianKeßler I added a different approach and you will certainly appreciate the need for the indirection.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to 'smuggle' material out of the group. With only one setting:

```latex
\NewDocumentCommand{\DeclareCategory}{ O{} m}
  {
    \group_begin:
      \keys_set:nn { categories } {#1}
    \exp_args:NNNV \group_end:
    \tl_set:Nn \l__category_key_tl \l__category_key_tl
      \exp_args:Nc\NewDocumentCommand{#2}{ }
        {
          %Do some stuff here with #2:
          called:~#2,~
          % Do some other stuff, using the \l__category_key_tl token list
          Value~is:~\tl_use:N\l__category_key_tl
        }
  }
```

With more, you'd save the material in a scratch `tl`, and use the same approach to move it outside of the group.

---

If, as seems likely, you want the *value* of the key rather than the variable, you'd want to arrange an indirection

```latex
\NewDocumentCommand{\DeclareCategory}{ O{} m}
  {
    \group_begin:
      \keys_set:nn { categories } {#1}
    \exp_args:NNNV \group_end:
    \tl_set:Nn \l__category_key_tl \l__category_key_tl
    \exp_args:NnV \__declarecategory:nN {#2} \l__category_key_tl
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__declarecategory:nN #1#2
  {
      \exp_args:Nc\NewDocumentCommand{#1}{ }
        {
          %Do some stuff here with #2:
          called:~#1,~
          % Do some other stuff, using the \l__category_key_tl token list
          Value~is:~#2
        }
  }
```

Comment: The replacement text would contain `\l__category_key`, as far as I can see, not the set value.

Comment: @egreg `\exp_args:NNNV \group_end: \tl_set:Nn <var> <var>` will smuggle the setting by one group, which seems to be the request. I agree that having `\l__category_key_tl` not the _value_ of `\l__category_key_tl` in the document command seems odd, but it appears to be the request :)

Comment: I'm not sure it is the requirement. It should be the value, as far as I can see.

Comment: @egreg Lets see what the OP says ....

Comment: Yes, I want access to the actual tokens stored in the list. Is this the supposed way to provide Syntax like `\foo[ key = value ]{...}` and process the keyvalue arguments only for this macro call when using expl3?

Answer (score 0):

I would just use `\tl_gset:cn` to globally define the command. Nesting document level NewDocumentCommand declaratiosn within the programming level expl3 code isn't necessarily wrong but always a bit suspicious.

Depending on the use case you could use an expl3 "new" version or as here just use `\t_gset` (which is `\gdef`, more or less)

```
 %     \exp_args:NNc\global\NewDocumentCommand{#2}{ }{...}
      \tl_gset:cn{#2}{...}
```

Or perhaps

```
 %     \exp_args:NNc\global\NewDocumentCommand{#2}{ }{...}
       \cs_new_protected:cpn{#2}{...}
```

which would throw an error if the name was not new.

Comment: `\cs_new_protected:cpn` seems better.

Comment: @egreg as I say "depending on the use case"   actually I'd be rather suspicious of using a "new" version at that point and triggering an error in the middle of  the expansion of the code, in most (or some) use cases you might have hoped to check such things before you got thisfar.

Comment: @egreg but I'll add that as a second possibility

Answer (score 0):

When the processed keyvalue arguments are only needed in the inner defined command (which is the case for me so far), it seems that the simplest solution  is to just `\keys_set:nn` *within* the newly defined DocumentCommand, and regularly apply grouping there.

Essentially, this postpones evaluation of the optional arguments until the internal defined macro is called (but has the downside of parsing these again every time).